# How to stop an anchor from redirecting using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I stop an anchor tag redirecting to another page if the user is not logged in?  I have a function to check if the user is logged in or not.  I want to do it with JQuery or JavaScript.  Here is what I have tried so far but with no results:

```
<a href="www.somewhere.com" id="yes">Read More</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            if(id == 'yes'){
                //i want to prevent
            }else{
                //redirect
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I would maybe suggest you use sessions that this method

Comment: You can return false, when an onclick event is triggered.

Comment: Authentication needs to be performed server-side in your PHP, not in JavaScript at all.

Comment: You have to return false

Comment: @agam360 not for *real* authentication.

Comment: @Greg, what do you mean by real? Ajax is technically originating from the server side, so there wont need to be any problems, if he uses sessions and ajax combined. am I wrong? (I'd like to know :) if so)

Comment: I expect you have a typo in your code, you probably don't mean to have `$id` but rather `id` as the variable name in the first few lines

Comment: you can also use return false on the click event

Comment: @agam360 Ajax is OK to be used in authentication procedures, but the authentication **must** occur on the server, not on the client like in this example.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Please use http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/aRBY4/6/

```
e.preventDefault()
```

**quote**

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be
>   triggered.

Also if I may suggest read this: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Hope this helps,

**sample code**

```
  $('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //do whatever
  });
```

**In your case** please try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(event) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if (id == 'yes') {
            event.preventDefault();
            //i want to prevent
        } else {
            //redirect
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: i have used the same method you mentioned but it returns undefined on click if i alert id of anchor.

Comment: @Ankit cool, so preventDefault aside, `:)` there is another issue with the selector which gets the `id` can you also paste your html in the question and I might help you out, cheers

Comment: i was missing id as my page was showing same code for two cases , Thanks alot @Tats,  problem resolved.

Comment: one more Question. As i have prevented onclick of anchor tag i also want to stop open in new tab.

Comment: Hiya @Ankit Stop opening tab: hmm either you can `return false` after `preventDefault` or use this API: http://api.jquery.com/stop/ worth thinking it through and asking a separate question `:)` just an idea if you cannot figure it out but above detail should help,

Comment: i have used mousedown function on place of click function that does the work capture every click including open in new tab , open in new window , everything goes fine but when use open in new tab then alert comes as wanted but when i check the checkbox of prevent from generating message then again on click or on open in new tab or window anchor redirects.

Comment: ola @Ankit again `:)` try replicating that in jsfiddle, I might take  a look and +1 for your question from my end, oh and `:P` its bit late at my end hence worth making a decent demo and ask a separate question carefully, anyhoo just an idea.

Answer (score 4):

Change your click event handler to this

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (id == 'yes')
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    else
    {
        //redirect
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
    $("a").on("click",function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         alert("Clicked");

     });
```

happy Coding;

Answer (score -1):

Use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/). It is used to prevent  the default action of the event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('a').click(function(){
          var id = $(this).attr('id');
         if(id == 'yes'){
             event.preventDefault() 
         }else{
            //redirect
         }
     });
});
</script>
```