# Django template and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

```js
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myanchor").href;
});
```

```html
<div><a href="{{ audio.get_api_url }}" ><i class="icon-control-play i-2x" id="target"></i></a> </div>
```

I need to send the api url to the my jquery function to call the ajax function to execute the code further. The page should not redirect to the api url, I cant figure this thing out.

Comment: I was trying to use DOM, `<div><a href="{{ audio.get_api_url }}" id="myanchor" ><i class="icon-control-play i-2x" id="target"></i></a> </div>` but it redirects the page to my api call

Comment: This code is sort of all over the place.  The purpose of Django is to prepare the variables and data which you will use in a webpage.  AJAX is a technology you use to obtain information by a client once it's rendered the webpage.  I would suggest first spending some time getting a static web page to work with an ajax call, then work on binding the variables to your Django template player.  Here's just one article on making AJAX calls: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: There is no `id="myanchor"` in your snippet

Answer (score 0):

The question should be simply **"how to avoid redirection on anchor tag and call function"**, how is it related to DJango templates ?

---

Anyway, you can avoid redirecting using JQuery's `preventDefault()` method. Here is the example:

```
$( "#target" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = document.getElementById("myanchor").href;
});
```

Checkout the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240897/how-to-stop-an-anchor-from-redirecting-using-jquery) for further explanation.